# C++/CX - Vector of Vectors?

Tags: vector, windows-runtime, c++-cx

Is it possible in C++/CX to have a Vector of Vectors? I'm just curious how the syntax would look. Currently, I have...

```
Vector<String^>^
```

...and I have found that I may actually need to have many of these Vector's, so I was hoping to use another Vector to contain all of these Vector's. Is that possible?

I have tried...

```
Vector<Vector<String^>^>^ blah;
```

...and that seems to compile, but then when I try to initialize it using...

```
Vector<Vector<String^>^>^ blah = ref new Vector<Vector<String^>^>();
```

...the compile fails with error...

```
 "'get': signature of public member contains native type 'std::equal_to<_Ty>'"
```

Comment: in C++ it would look like `vector<vector<int>>` for example

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

```
Vector<IVector<String^>^>^ blah = ref new Vector<IVector<String^>^>();
```

Note that it's a Vector of IVector now, which apparently compiles.